# How to detect Internet Explorer 11 and below versions?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm wondering how I could detect if the user viewing my website is using Internet Explorer 11 or below versions with Javascript.

**It should be compatible and works with all these versions.**

How to achieve that ?

Comment: If the `string` `Trident` is in `window.navigator.userAgent`.

Comment: @AjAX. Trident is only for IE11, older versions of IE used MSIE

Comment: @RyanWilson Nope. It’s — not. `Trident` is in all down to `IE 6`. Both are.

Comment: @AjAX ok. Was not aware of both being in there down to IE6, but still best to check for both in case some ancient computer is out there running older version than IE6.

Comment: @DerekBrown , That's not correct because I don't want to detect only version 11 , I get the answer so thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here you go, this should work for you:

```
//Per Icycool, one liner
//function isIE(){
//                 return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
//               }

function isIE() {
    const ua = window.navigator.userAgent; //Check the userAgent property of the window.navigator object
    const msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '); // IE 10 or older
    const trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/'); //IE 11
    
    return (msie > 0 || trident > 0);
}


//function to show alert if it's IE
function ShowIEAlert(){
    if(isIE()){
       alert("User is using IE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I want to show an alert if it's true , Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @Danny added another function into the example to show alert if isIE() returns true.

Comment: `window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/)` if you want to do it in 1 line

Comment: @Icycool Thank you for the suggestion. I added it to the answer as another option.

Comment: @Icycool Why group the Regex? `window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/)` should do it.

Comment: @Timm uhm just old habit of using string pattern in case there are other parts in the regex. You're right in this case the brackets are not needed.

Comment: Use `var` not `const` if you want to be compatible with older versions of IE!

Comment: Thanks a lot. saved my day

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard You're welcome. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 9):

Check for **documentmode** - the IE only property:

```
if (document.documentMode) 
    alert('this is IE');
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to streamline the correct answer. This returns `true` or `false`:

```
function is_IE() {
  return (window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/) !== null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler version, returns boolean

```js
function isIE() {
  return !!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/);
}
```

Comment: FYI `/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)` returns bool.